# Scala - object X is not member of package Y

Tags: scala

I have the following two files:

**MainObject.scala**

```
import mypkg.MyObject._  
object MainObject {}
```

**mypkg/MyObject.scala**

```
package mypkg  
object MyObject {}
```

Then when I try to compile with `scalac MainObject.scala` I get the error

> MainObject.scala:1: error: object MyObject is not a member of package
>   mypkg

Any idea as to why this error would occur?

Answer (score 6):

You need to supply the two files to compile to `scalac`:

```
scalac MainObject.scala mypkg/MyObject.scala
```

This works fine for me with your code.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Not the most straight-forward error message.